# Pil Image crop is increasing the file size of an image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pagespeed-insights

I've discovered that I can get better [PageSpeeds](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) if I split my website background image up into smaller images. I've created a python script to do this, to avoid needing to create 6 copies and cropping them in preview every time I need to change something, but the cropped images are too big. The bottom one is a larger file size than my original image

[The image which I am splitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFy46.jpg) (154 kb)

[The bottom split image which is larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW05c.jpg) (160 kb)

**script which splits the image up into smaller images**

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import ntpath

def crop(pathToFile, height, width=False):
    im = Image.open(pathToFile)
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    [name, ext] = ntpath.basename(pathToFile).split('.')
    if(not width):
        width = imgwidth
    k=0
    for i in range(0,imgheight,height):
        for j in range(0,imgwidth,width):
            box = (j, i, j+width, i+height)
            a = im.crop(box)
            a.save(os.path.join("./" + name + str(k) + "." + ext), compress_level=9, optimize=True)
            k +=1

pathToFile = './path/to/wheat-background.jpg'
crop(pathToFile, 933)
```

Comment: you would get better performance splitting it into 2 images and then converting to webP for browsers that support, 1 for above the fold and 1 for the rest of the page (lazy loaded in). Also for the images you linked they show as  154kb for the full image and 73kb for the bottom image so not sure what you mean there? I don't know python but "compress_level" is likely to be what you need to adjust, normally you would set 75% quality on a jpeg so whatever the equivalent is to that. Lastly I would use the `<picture>` element to serve different sizes for different screens sizes as image is large.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I use gatsby, which handles a lot of the different sizes and webp stuff. Thanks for the 2 images tip, would it really make that much of a difference? And the second image must have gotten condensed when I uploaded it.

Comment: Yes - one of the factors of speed is number of requests, a browser can handle (typically) 8 requests at a time, meaning that for every 8 requests you have the round-trip time associated with making requests. On a mobile 4G connection this can be 150ms, 250ms or more. So if you have 24 requests you have at least 600ms of "dead time" waiting for the round trip time. the 25th request adds another 200ms etc. In general fewer requests is actually better. However as "above the fold" is the critical part of *perceived* speed I suggest splitting it in 2 due to the file size. Its a balancing act.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie If I have a lot of images, do you know if there's a better way to import them? I'm already using gatsby and graphql, but would svg or something be better for this?

Comment: SVG is only useful for illustrations, icons etc. It is a vector format so not useful for general images. It is great for performance, especially anything "above the fold" as you can inline the SVG to reduce requests. This (https://css-tricks.com/the-complete-guide-to-lazy-loading-images/) is a great beginners introduction to lazy loading. You essentially only load images that are in the viewport. A better version is to lazy load everything about 1 page down so the user (nearly) never sees it happening. For lots of small images look up CSS image sprites. https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/